# JPA excesive querys for mapping an entity

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jboss, ejb-3.0, nativequery

I have the following entity:

```
    @Name("estructuraOrganica")
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "srht_estructuras_organicas")
    public class EstructuraOrganica extends EntidadBasica implements Auditable,
    Desplegable<EstructuraOrganica> {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@NotNull
@Length(max = 50)
@Column(name = "codigo", nullable = false, length = 50)
private String codigo;

@Length(max = 300)
@Column(name = "nombre", nullable = true, length = 160)
private String nombre;

@Column(name = "institucion_id")
private Long institucionId;

@NotNull
@Length(max = 1)
@Column(name = "es_uarh", nullable = false, length = 1)
private String esUARH;

@NotNull
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "catalogo_jerarquia_proceso_unidad_id", nullable = false)
@Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
private Catalogo catalogoJerarquiaProcesoUnidad;

@NotNull
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "estatuto_id", nullable = false)
private Estatuto estatuto;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH)
@JoinColumn(name = "estructura_organica_padre_id", nullable = true)
private EstructuraOrganica estructuraOrganicaPadre;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH)
@JoinColumn(name = "padre_auxiliar_estructura_id", nullable = true)
private EstructuraOrganica estructuraOrganicaJerarquia;

@NotNull
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "estado_id", nullable = false)
@Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
private Estado estado;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH, fetch = FetchType.LAZY,                             mappedBy                    =                           "estructuraOrganicaPadre")
@OrderBy(value = "codigo")
private List<EstructuraOrganica> estructurasOrganicas;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "estructuraOrganica")
private List<OrganigramaPosicion> organigramasPosiciones;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "estructuraOrganica")
@Where(clause = "estado_id=1")
private List<OrganigramaPosicion> organigramasPosicionesActivas;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "estructuraOrganicaPadre")
@OrderBy(value = "codigo")
@Where(clause = "estado_id=1")
private List<EstructuraOrganica> estructurasOrganicasActivas;

@Column(name = "estado_plan_vacaciones")
private Integer estadoPlanVacaciones;

@Column(name = "tipo")
private Integer tipo;

@Column(name = "puesto_jefe_inmediato")
private Long puestoJefeInmediato;   

@Length(max = 10)
@Column(name = "codigo_mef", nullable = true, length = 10)
private String codigoMef;

@Transient
private Boolean puedeEliminarse;

@Transient
private Boolean uarh;

@Transient
private Boolean puedeGrabarse;

@Transient
private RegimenDePersonal regimenDePersonal;

@Column(name="institucion_desconcentrada_id")
private Long institucionDesconcentradaId;

... Getters and Setters omitted...

   }
```

Now the JPQL query to find a certain instance of this entity is the following:

```
   SELECT o FROM EstructuraOrganica o WHERE o.estatuto.institucion.id=:institucionId and        o.estructuraOrganicaPadre is null AND o.estado.id=1 ORDER BY o.codigo ASC")
```

However, the problem is that this simple query is generating an excesive count of calls to the database... doing selects basically. A native sql for doing the same could be:

```
    SELECT * from sch_senres.srht_estructuras_organicas,
          sch_senres.srht_estatutos,
          sch_senres.srht_instituciones,
          sch_senres.srht_estados
    WHERE sch_senres.srht_estructuras_organicas.estatuto_id=sch_senres.srht_estatutos.id
    AND   sch_senres.srht_estructuras_organicas.estado_id=sch_senres.srht_estados.id
    AND   sch_senres.srht_estatutos.institucion_id=sch_senres.srht_instituciones.id
    AND   sch_senres.srht_instituciones.id=91122
    AND   sch_senres.srht_estados.id=1
    AND   sch_senres.srht_estructuras_organicas.estructura_organica_padre_id IS NULL
    ORDER BY sch_senres.srht_estructuras_organicas.codigo
```

So the idea was to create a NativeQuery like this:

```
    Query query=entityManager.createNativeQuery("SELECT * from  sch_senres.srht_estructuras_organicas,"+                                                    "sch_senres.srht_estatutos,sch_senres.srht_instituciones,"+
                                                "sch_senres.srht_estados "+
                                                "WHERE sch_senres.srht_estructuras_organicas.estatuto_id=sch_senres.srht_estatutos.id "+
                                                "AND   sch_senres.srht_estructuras_organicas.estado_id=sch_senres.srht_estados.id "+
                                                "AND   sch_senres.srht_estatutos.institucion_id=sch_senres.srht_instituciones.id "+
                                                "AND   sch_senres.srht_instituciones.id= :institucionId "+
                                                "AND   sch_senres.srht_estados.id=1 "+
                                                "AND   sch_senres.srht_estructuras_organicas.estructura_organica_padre_id IS NULL "+
                                                "ORDER BY sch_senres.srht_estructuras_organicas.codigo", EstructuraOrganica.class);
    query.setParameter("institucionId", institucionId);
```

However I got no result... hibernate continues doing like 50 calls to the database. Does anybody know why is this happening, and how could I avoid so many calls?. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a lot of associations mapped in that class. I expect all the selects are happening when you're using, and therefore initializing, the lazy references. If it's not causing problems, just let it be. Otherwise read about [Fetching Strategies](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/performance.html#performance-fetching) to understand the different ways you can tune hibernate queries.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to have a close look at when exactly the DB calls happen, and what exactly is queried in them.

If you haven't already done this, I'd suggest to activate logging of SQL statements by hibernate:
You have to set logging like this:
`org.hibernate.type` to TRACE level.
`org.hibernate.SQL` to DEBUG level.

This will show/log all the SQL statements and parameters that hibernate is using for your persistence.

In Log4J the above loggin would be configured like this...

```
<category name="org.hibernate.type">
  <priority value="TRACE"/>
  <appender-ref ref="[..whatever appender you want..]"/>
</category>
<category name="org.hibernate.SQL">
  <priority value="DEBUG"/>
  <appender-ref ref="[..whatever appender you want..]"/>
</category>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you all were right, the problem was that the @PostLoad method was referencing the relationship of the same entity, in other words, it was calling the estructurasOrganicas property. This was causing a recursive fetch from the database. I didn't see the PostLoad method at first time, this was the problem. Thanks a lot.